# Mathematical variables while select querying in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

I have some huge query which returns data, some of the columns are to be manipulated by math equations for ex:

```
select 
    num1,
    num2,
    num2 + num1 as num3,
    num1 * num3 as num4
from my Tables...
```

The problem arises when i try to reuse the calculated `num3` in my calculation of `num4`. Could it be that I can't use such syntax, and should use in this way:

```
select 
    num1,
    num2,
    num2 + num1 as num3,
    num1 * (num2 + num1) as num4
from my Tables...
```

It doesn't seem like a good way imo. Is there any other way?

Comment: yes, you can't do it that way. Also any other way, in which you can do it, will just increase the lines of code.

Comment: You could use a subquery that defines an alias you can reuse in the outer query, but is repeating that addition much of a problem really; why isn't a good way? (With a complicated calculation it makes maintenance a bit harder, but this looks simple enough for that to not really be an issue.)

Comment: @SudiptaMondal so the only choice is to redo the operations?

Comment: @AlexPoole well it is not that a problem, however I feel like it there might be a better solution

Comment: @AlexPoole - with a complicated calculation, there may also be a performance issue. Oracle may cache the result of a deterministic function calculation, but I don't believe it does the same with the result of a complicated, deterministic calculation. If so, it is better to do some computations in a subquery and then the rest in an outer query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to either repeat the calculation as you are currently doing, or use a subquery which assigns an alias to the column expression, which you can then refer to in the outer query:

```
select 
    num1,
    num2,
    num3,
    num1 * num3 as num4
from (
    select 
        num1,
        num2,
        num2 + num1 as num3
    from my Tables
)
```

You can't refer to a column alias in the same level of query, except in the order-by clause. [From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55280):

> ***c_alias***
>   Specify an alias for the column expression. Oracle Database will use this alias in the column heading of the result set. The `AS` keyword is optional. The alias effectively renames the select list item for the duration of the query. The alias can be used in the *order_by_clause* but not other clauses in the query.

The last sentence is the important bit.Using a subquery is OK though as that is a different level.

Answer (score 1):

As your calculation such as (num2 + num1 as num3) in main query can not be anywhere, because

> **"as" keyword will make only alias name for the column header**

but this column value can not be used by else where.

If you want to use that expression value in another place you need to write it as inner query then use it in outer query how many times as you want.